# Mysql Replication two databases with diffrent table schemas

Tags: java, mysql, database, database-replication

i am developing web-base distributed database system [ Java RMI with Mysql ]. How do i replicate data between two databases(@ diffrent locations) with different table schema. For example, DB at Company A have Table with 3 columns ( Id, First_name, Last_name ) and DB at Company B have Table with 2 Columns ( Id, Name ). Now i want to replicate data from Company A to B. i have to merge ( First_name and Last_name ) of Company A and Store it into Company B Table ( Name ) column.is there any way to configure mysql to do so. Or Should i write Middle ware code (in java or something).. please any suggestions.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you have to write some code.

You can write middleware code if both tables are in different database location.

I both databases are at the same location you can write a trigger on table A1's insert.

Comment: - can you be more specific on middleware code. please

Comment: You can write two insert queries on individual tables with required fields using two different connection to different databases.